# Why i'm getting "PLS-00302: component 'TABLE_NAME' must be declared"?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

I'm trying to create a fairly simple stored procedure in Oracle 12.2 DB:

```
create or replace procedure list_tables (
    p_src_schema    varchar2
)
as
    l_src_schema    varchar2(30)    := upper(p_src_schema);
begin
    for x in (select table_name name from all_tables where owner = l_src_schema
              and not regexp_like(table_name, '(AAA|BKP_|LOG_|TMP_|TEST|XX).*')
              order by table_name)
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(x.table_name);
    end loop;
end;
/
show errors
```

and i'm getting the following error:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
11/9     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
11/32    PLS-00302: component 'TABLE_NAME' must be declared
```

the error occurs in the following line: `dbms_output.put_line(x.table_name);`

**Question:** what do I do wrong? I must be overseeing something very obvious...

---

**UPDATE:** the alias `name` has been "added" after pressing `<TAB>` by  the dBeaver autocompletion - and I didn't notice it.
;)

Comment: Side observation - you are selecting from ALL_TABLES.  That will only get the tables that the user executing the procedure has privileges on.  Suppose the input schema is FRED, and the procedure is being executed by SCOTT, and FRED owns tables that SCOTT does not have privs on.  Those tables will not be reported.  I think you should be selecting from DBA_TABLES, and make sure the user executing the procedure has privs on that view.

Comment: @EdStevens, i don't have DBA privs, so i can't use DBA_* views)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you used column **alias**:

```
select table_name name from
                  ----
```

which means that you should have used

```
dbms_output.put_line(x.name);
```

instead.

Comment: OMG, that was so stupid of me! Thanks a lot! :)